# Error 424 when passing Range parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and I am having an error with this very simple code:

```
Sub sub1()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
    sub2 (myCell)      '<<<<------- Error 424
End Sub

Sub sub2(x As Range)
    'not doing anything yet
End Sub
```

I am receiving `Error 424` when invoking the `sub2` from `sub1`. In my mind, this should work, since `myCell` is a Range... any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ty removing either removing the brackets, or adding a `Call` ie:

```
Sub Opt1()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
    sub2 myCell     
End Sub

Sub sub2(x As Range)
MsgBox x.Address
End Sub
```

*or*

```
Sub Opt2()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
    Call sub2(myCell)
End Sub

Sub sub2(x As Range)
MsgBox x.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: What a shame, it was that. But the brackets are allowed if I don't declare a type for the parameter...weird, thanks a lot!

Comment: @edutesoy No probs, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx