# subroutine returns Mistach

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying I have a sub-routine called **DBExcelExport** which takes only one variable recForm but when I call it on a Button is gives an error 13 Mismatch.

Below is my Sub Routine

```
Sub DBExcelExport(recForm As Form)
 Dim objXLS As Object
 Dim wks As Object
 Public rsc As Recordset
 Dim idx As Long
 Set rsc = recForm.RecordsetClone
 rsc.MoveLast
 rsc.MoveFirst
 Set objXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 objXLS.Workbooks.Add
 Set wks = objXLS.Worksheets(1)
 For idx = 0 To rsc.Fields.Count - 1
   wks.Cells(1, idx + 1).Value = rsc.Fields(idx).Name
 Next
 wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(1, rsc.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
 wks.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsc, rsc.RecordCount, rsc.Fields.Count
 objXLS.Visible = True
 Set objXLS = Nothing
End Sub
```

And this How I call it

```
DBExcelExport (Me.ProjectsList.Form)
```

Comment: I solved it by adding Call on DBExcelExport (Me.ProjectsList.Form)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776631/error-424-when-passing-range-parameter/20776796#20776796

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding Call on DBExcelExport (Me.ProjectsList.Form) 
to appear as below

```
Call DBExcelExport (Me.ProjectsList.Form)
```